# About "best" , "the best" , and "most"

Tags: adverbs

Which is correct, "I like you the best" or "I like you best"?

And I hear " I like you most" is incorrect, so which is correct, "I love you most" or "I love you best"? Are there any rules that which one should be used?

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences could mean the same thing, however

> I like you best.
>   *I like chocolate best, better than anything else*

can be used when what one is choosing from is not specified

> I like you *the* best.
>   *Between chocolate, vanilla, and strawberry, I like vanilla the best*

can be used when choosing from some choices.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Is " I like you most" incorrect?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "I like you most" is not natural English, but I've said it a few times to my wife, for fun  :)

Comment: How about "I love you"? Which is correct, best or most?

Comment: Ah, the difference between semantics and romantics... "I love you more than anything in the whole *(wide)* world." = "I love you most *(of all)*." to say "I love you *(the)* best" though grammatically correct, may not be the best thing to say romantically (since she will be wondering what she's being compared to...)

Comment: Thanks again. I have a question why " I like you most" is unnatural but " I love you most" is natural. Why?

Comment: I think it could be the intensity of the emotion, "most" is a superlative and "love" is more intense than "like".  "I like you most" is not incorrect, but culturally I people would expect "I love you most" / "I like you best" (Best Friends Forever). To say "I like you most" is a little bit of a put down, the listener could be disappointed.